# Font properties

Tags: c#, fonts, coding-style, colors, size

I have a text file with the following info in it, on a single line:

```
-16777216
Arial
7.8
Bold
```

(-16777216   is the color of the text in ARGB format).. How would I be able to set this text as the font properties for a label at runtime? I have googled this but couldn't find anything related specifically to my problem. Can anyone please offer any suggestions/help?

thanks lots :)
jase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all four lines are always there...

```
var fontSettings = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("fontsettings.txt");

int color = int.Parse(fontSettings[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
string family = fontSettings[1];
float size = float.Parse(fontSettings[2], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
FontStyle style = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), fontSettings[3]);

label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(color);
label1.Font = new Font(family, size, style);
```

Comment: hi kawa the following lines have invalid argument errors and i dont know how to fix them:

                        color = int.Parse(fontSettings[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
                        font = fontSettings[1];
                        float se = float.Parse(fontSettings[2], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        FontStyle sle = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), fontSettings[3]);

Comment: oops MY BAD few spelling mistakes LOL thank s heaps for your answer +1

Comment: think i need more coffee this morning

Comment: That kind of thing happens. I for one had failed to consider , vs . differences in the float conversion, causing huge text!

Comment: hey kawa, i keep running into this error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array." on the following line of code, can u please help me figure out whats going on?:


int c = int.Parse(fontSettings[0], System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);

Comment: This is why I made it several lines. Add a breakpoint and watch the values closely for errors. I used your settings (-16777216 Arial 7.8 Bold) as you typed them, each on a different line. fontSettings should contain each of these as a seperate string.

Comment: should it matter if there is other information on other lines in the same text file?

Comment: As long as the first four are the font settings, the fifth, sixth or whatever-th are irrelevant. This code, as I gave you, stops caring after the fourth line (which is fontSettings[3]).